# How do I prevent a programmatic form submit from JS?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an external library that's calling `form.submit()`.  No matter what I do, I can't seem to catch the event when it's called directly like that.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/yXsWc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of intercepting the event, have you tried intercepting the `submit()` call itself?  You could do something like replace the default `submit()` function with one of your choosing that only submits if some flag is set.  For instance:

```
var formElem = document.getElementById("myForm");
formElem.oldSubmit = formElem.submit;
formElem.submit = function(myFlag) {
    if (myFlag) {
        document.getElementById("myForm").oldSubmit();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit hack-ish, but you could unbind the `click` event from that certain element, then re-bind it to work the way you want it to.

```
$('button').unbind('click').click(form.onsubmit);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/yXsWc/1/)